# batch copy and suppress all output

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, copy

I have a batch file where I am copying files from folders to a new destination.

The folder list is generated by the batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@REM Set defaults
SET BASE_FLDR=.\
SET BLD_TYPE=Release
SET DST_FLDR=SC_APP
@REM Check if base folder specified, if not default to current location
IF NOT [%1] == [] SET BASE_FLDR=%1
@REM Check if build type specified, if not default to Release
IF NOT [%2] == [] SET BLD_TYPE=%2
@REM Display parameters
ECHO Base folder: %BASE_FLDR%
ECHO Build type : %BLD_TYPE%
@REM Does destination folder exist?
IF NOT EXIST %DST_FLDR% MKDIR %DST_FLDR%
@REM Create list of subfolders to search
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('"DIR %BASE_FLDR% /S /B /A:D | FINDSTR /EIC:"%BLD_TYPE%" "') DO (
    @COPY /Y "%%F"\*.DLL "%DST_FLDR%" >NUL
    @COPY /Y "%%F"\*.EXE "%DST_FLDR%" >NUL
)
```

During the copy process I see lots of:

> ```
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

I've tried various things but have not been able to prevent this message from being displayed.

`@` doesn't stop it, neither does redirecting the output to `NUL`, I also tried launching in another `CMD`, doesn't stop it happening either.

Comment: redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to NUL: ` >nul 2>&1` (for some reason if the source does not exist, the errormessage goes to STDOUT, while if the destination folder does not exist, it goes to STDERR). (for correct syntax, you should `copy /y "%%F\*.DLL" "%DST_FLDR%\  >nul 2>&1`)

Comment: FYI, `[` and `]` have no special meaning, and will therefore not protect any poison characters in your input arguments. I would suggest therefore, that you use `IF NOT "%~1" == "" SET "BASE_FLDR=%~1"` and `IF NOT "%~2" == "" SET "BLD_TYPE=%~2"` instead.

Comment: Additionally, you should use `IF NOT EXIST "%DST_FLDR%\" MKDIR "%DST_FLDR%"`, _note the backslash which ensures that you're checking for the existence of a directory, not a file_. And for safety, based upon the advice in my previous comment, you should be using `DIR "%BASE_FLDR%"` not `DIR %BASE_FLDR%`.

Comment: Credit for the answer has to go to Stephan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, see comment by Stephan.

Completed script:

```
    @ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    @REM Set defaults
    SET BASE_FLDR=.\
    SET BLD_TYPE=Release
    @REM Check if base folder specified, if not default to current location
    IF NOT [%1] == [] SET BASE_FLDR=%1
    @REM Check if build type specified, if not default to Release
    IF NOT [%2] == [] SET BLD_TYPE=%2
    SET DST_FLDR=%BASE_FLDR%sc_app
    @REM Display parameters
    ECHO Base folder: %BASE_FLDR%
    ECHO Build type : %BLD_TYPE%
    ECHO Destination folder : %DST_FLDR%
    ECHO Please wait
    @REM Does destination folder exist?
    IF NOT EXIST %DST_FLDR% (
        ECHO Creating %DST_FLDR%
        MKDIR %DST_FLDR%
    )
    @REM Create list of subfolders to search
    ECHO Copying DLL's and EXE's to %DST_FLDR%
    FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('"DIR %BASE_FLDR% /S /B /A:D | FINDSTR /EIC:"%BLD_TYPE%" "') DO (
        ECHO | SET /p="."
        @COPY /Y "%%F"\*.DLL "%DST_FLDR%" >NUL 2>&1
        @COPY /Y "%%F"\*.EXE "%DST_FLDR%" >NUL 2>&1
    )
    ECHO "Copy complete"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your self accepted answer, I have decided to post this because you've ignored all of the advice I provided in the comments:

**Please note:** This is not how I'd perform the task, so it is not provided as an answer per se, more a supplement to your own answer.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM Set defaults
SET "BASE_FLDR=."
SET "BLD_TYPE=Release"

REM Check if base folder specified, if not default to current location
IF NOT "%~1" == "" SET "BASE_FLDR=%~1"

REM Check if build type specified, if not default to Release
IF NOT "%~2" == "" SET "BLD_TYPE=%~2"
SET "DST_FLDR=%BASE_FLDR%\sc_app"

REM Display parameters
ECHO Base folder: %BASE_FLDR%
ECHO Build type: %BLD_TYPE%
ECHO Destination folder: %DST_FLDR%
ECHO Please wait

REM Does destination folder exist?
IF NOT EXIST "%DST_FLDR%\" (
    ECHO Creating %DST_FLDR%
    MD "%DST_FLDR%"
)

REM Create list of subfolders to search
ECHO Copying DLL's and EXE's to %DST_FLDR%
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%F IN ('"DIR /B /S /AD "%BASE_FLDR%" | FINDSTR /EIC:"%BLD_TYPE%""') DO (
    ECHO | SET /P "=."
    COPY /Y "%%F\*.DLL" "%DST_FLDR%" >NUL 2>&1
    COPY /Y "%%F\*.EXE" "%DST_FLDR%" >NUL 2>&1
)
ECHO "Copy complete"
```

Comment: The working solution was already posted by Stephan, before you!

Comment: If you don't want to learn, that's your perogative, just remember to bookmark this question so you can revisit my answer when your non robust code fails. It's not as if your methodology is the most efficient way to do it anyhow, I simply copied your inefficient method and added the fixes advised in my ignored comments.